# Suspensão de utilização do chat

Tags: suporte, chat, suspensão

Alguém me sabe explicar porque fui suspenso do chat por 30 minutos?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Pelo que percebi foi o [bot Feeds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds).

Comment: eeeeiiiiiitttaaa peste!

Comment: não sei não meu irmão!

Comment: Parece que o bot não gostou da música

Comment: Amigão, você está falando muito no chat. kkkkk

Comment: @emanuelsn deve ser isso, meu patrão mandou bloquear :P

Comment: o bot acho que o seu avatar era concorrente dele. Aí mandou te bloquear.  kkkk

Comment: Eu sou o lado negro da força do avatar do @JorgeB.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino ou você é o anti-jorgeb. tipo a sombra do link no Ocarine of time ou então o anti-paladino no 3d&t :)

Comment: Jedi X Sith @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk. Acho que era o vídeo que tinha alguma coisa de "periquita"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Você postou o link de um vídeo marcado para maiores de 18 anos e tá perguntando porque foi suspenso?

Não faço ideia......

Comment: Não reparei que era +18, como era uma música nunca pensei. Desculpa.

Comment: @JorgeB. O Youtube não pede confirmação de idade se você já tá logado (e tem mais de 18)... É um erro fácil de cometer. Ainda assim, o vídeo por sí só, e a letra, deviam ser dica suficiente de que não deveriam estar no chat.

Comment: Tens razão @Gabe.